# Neural network classifier

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pattern-recognition

When you have 2 classes A with 2 elements and B with one element in 1D space in any configuration. Task is to distinguish between the two classes, to classify them. If you can choose arbitrary activation function, what is the minimal number of neurons that can solve this.

I am thinking that you always have to use at least two neurons or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is somewhat related to the classical XOR problem for perceptrons. Let us suppose for a moment, that it's about a neural network with the specific activation function - binary threshold - which perceptron has. Then the task turns into 1D XOR problem, and then indeed you need 2 neurons in hidden layer and 1 neuron in output layer to solve it. But you mention that an arbitrary activation function can be chosen. In this case we can choose [radial basis function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) (RBF) network. If it is possible to denote class A as output value greater than T and class B as output value less than T, then only 1 RBF neuron will suffice to distinguish the classes. If you want every class to have its own output (which value can be treated as a probability measure of input data belonging to corresponding class), then you need 2 RBF neurons.